# VS: статическая линковка std библиотеки

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, static

Скажите можно ли все библиотеки линковать динамически (то есть с ключем /MD), а стандартную библиотеку - статически (/MT)? Статическая стандартная WINDOWS библиотека назывется - LIBCPMT.LIB.

https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/154753/description-of-the-default-c-and-c-libraries-that-a-program-will-link

Comment: Приведенная ссылка содержит устаревшую информацию, аж 2008 года. Смотрите [Introducing the Universal CRT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/03/03/introducing-the-universal-crt/).

Comment: У меня есть подозрение что на самом деле вы хотите, чтобы ваши динамические библиотеки линковали рантайм динамически, но при этом импортировали все функции рантайм библиотеки из .exe файла чтобы не тащить еще и пачку отдельных рантайм библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

Нет. Эти ключи говорят линковщику какой рантайм использовать. Если вы будете линковать 2 библиотеки в один exe/dll файл, которые собраны с различными версиями рантайма, то линкер будет ругаться, что у вас задублированы все функции этих рантаймов. Напрмер, две версии оператора `new`, одна статическая, другая динамическая, какую надо линковать?

Если очень хочется, то можно к .exe файлу собраному с /MD залинковать .dll, которая собрана с /MT, т.к. за "границу" dll'ки рантайм не просочится. Но так делать опастно, т.к. может получится так, что объект создан в .exe через статический оператор `new`, а удален внутри .dll через динамический `delete`. Да там много подобных приколов.

Comment: Имеется ввиду что ключ компилятора `/md`, и ключ линкера - `/nodefaultlib`,  и потом - ручками - динамическую `msvcrt.lib` (та что с ключем `/md`) и статическую `libcpmt.lib` (та что с `/mt`). Напоминаю - ключ по умолчанию - `/md`. Но это ничего не значит , если '/nodefaultlib', так же ? Вообщем можно ли это сделать?

Comment: @Andreyua Это радикально отличается от того, что вы спрашиваете в своем вопросе.  Фраза "ручками - динамическую msvcprt.lib" вообще без смысла. Опишите подробно что вы все-таки хотите получить. `/nodefaultlib` обычно подразумевает, что стандартные библиотеки не будут использоваться.

Comment: динамическую `msvcprt.lib` - я исправил.
стандартные библиотеки не будут использоваться - так стандартные и есть это: `msvcrt.lib` и это: `libcpmt.lib`.

Comment: @Andreyua `msvcprt.lib` - это библиотека импорта для динамического подключения рантайма. Подключать ее руками смысла не имеет. Подключать `msvcrt.lib` и `libcpmt.lib` одновременно опять же не имеет смысла и не соответствует тому, что написано в вопросе.

Comment: msvcprt.lib - это для статического(да и забыли уже о ней, я же исправил, говорю , выше посмотрите то...). msvcrt.lib и libcpmt.lib одновременно опять же не имеет смысла - объясните почему...

Comment: @Andreyua По порядку: в своем вопросе вы спрашиваете "можно ли все библиотеки линковать динамически (то есть с ключем /MD), а стандартную библиотеку - статически" - ответ да, можно (только осторожно) и это ни разу те то же самое, что линковать одновременно msvcrt.lib и libcpmt.lib. Ответ товарища fft в этом плане неверный, так как линкер как раз таки будет предательски молчать, так как он будет не в курсе, что динамически линкуемые библиотеки кроме экспортируемых символов содержат еще и рантайм.

Comment: @Andreyua А линковать `msvcrt.lib` и `libcpmt.lib` одновременно не имеет смысла, так так экспортируемые символы в них как раз будут дублироваться.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68309/discussion-between-andreyua-and-vtt).